# Why is find running here?

Tags: performance, ram

I noticed very high IOwait, even copying/pasting from NetBeans to Firefox was taking several minutes and hanging for a long while. In powertop, I noticed:

```
            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
          0.0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: eth1 (wl)
        100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
         75.7%                      Device         Display backlight
        100.0%                      Device         USB device: usb-device-05ac-8205
        308.1 µs/s      16.9        Process        [rcu_sched]
        317.3 µs/s       1.7        Process        [ksoftirqd/0]
          2.6 ms/s       4.6        Process        compiz
          1.8 ms/s      15.0        Process        gnome-terminal
          8.0 ms/s      0.00        kWork          acpi_os_execute_deferred
          7.3 ms/s      0.00        Timer          wl_timer
          6.3 ms/s      34.6        Process        /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race ( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fst
          2.8 ms/s      16.1        Process        /usr/bin/X :0 -core -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
          2.4 ms/s      0.15        Process        [kswapd0]
          1.3 ms/s      0.00        Process        /usr/sbin/preload -s /var/lib/preload/preload.state
          1.1 ms/s      0.00        Process        /usr/sbin/macfanctld
          1.0 ms/s      14.3        Interrupt      [45] i915
          0.9 ms/s       7.0        Timer          tick_sched_timer
          0.7 ms/s      0.00        Interrupt      [21] uhci_hcd:usb7
          0.7 ms/s      10.2        kWork          od_dbs_timer
        659.0 µs/s      0.05        Process        indicator-multiload
        649.5 µs/s       0.4        Interrupt      [9] RCU(softirq)
        643.8 µs/s      0.00        Process        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
        641.7 µs/s      33.5        Interrupt      [4] block(softirq)
        629.7 µs/s       0.7        Process        /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
        585.4 µs/s      0.05        Process        powertop
        498.7 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [43] SATA controller
        371.8 µs/s      0.00        Timer          delayed_work_timer_fn
        301.4 µs/s      0.15        kWork          atp_reinit
        299.4 µs/s      0.05        kWork          disk_events_workfn
        185.3 µs/s      13.5        Interrupt      [21] ata_piix
        171.3 µs/s       2.6        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
        162.5 µs/s      0.05        Process        [ksoftirqd/1]
        152.6 µs/s      0.10        Process        /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq
        148.5 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [0] timer/0
        146.2 µs/s       2.4        Process        /usr/sbin/mysqld
        134.8 µs/s      0.10        Process        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application-service
        121.7 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [1] timer(softirq)
        115.9 µs/s      0.00        Timer          timeout_func
        109.8 µs/s      0.00        Timer          rh_timer_func
        109.7 µs/s      0.00        Process        /usr/bin/sort -z -f
        109.3 µs/s       0.7        Interrupt      [6] tasklet(softirq)
        102.3 µs/s      0.00        Process        //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
        101.1 µs/s      0.00        Interrupt      [21] ehci_hcd:usb1
         78.5 µs/s      0.15        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)
```

What is this find running, 34.6 events/second, is this what is making everything slow?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely started by a cronjob and it's running an indexer for locatedb.
While it's running it will make things slow, but it should only run daily, and shouldn't take too too terribly long.

See related info for Debian here (yours might be under a different cron than cron.daily): http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2011/07/msg00678.html and http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/448976-mysterious-find.html

Comment: Good guess, but `crontab -l` shows "no crontab", with or without sudo.

Comment: "crontab -l" will show you just the users (or root's crontab), if you run "ls -d /etc/cron.*" you will see a number of cron folders, on my system:
/etc/cron.daily/
/etc/cron.hourly/
/etc/cron.monthly/
/etc/cron.weekly/
which run at the specified intervals.  I'm suggesting the find is being started by one of these cronjobs.